# Display Null if datagridview Column is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a gridview with few column cells. all i want is to check an empty cells and write null by default. if some of the columns are not filled., i want a default null text to the specific cells that are ommited

I tried to create something like this but it is not working as i don't know how i can take it further

```
          private void Gridview_Output_CellFormatting_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
         { 
            string _Car = string.Empty;
            string _Dealer = string.Empty;
            string _Model = string.Empty;
            int gridcount = Gridview.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < gridcount; i++)
            {
                _Car = "";
                _Dealer = "";
                _Model = "";

                if (Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    _Car = "Null";
                }
                else
                {
                    _Car = Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    _Dealer = "Null";
                }
                else
                {
                    _Dealer = Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    _Model = "Null";
                }
                else
                {
                    _Model = Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you include the markup of your gridview?

Comment: mybad, I thought it was web form.

Comment: ok. how can i do it or make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `DataGridView`'s `CellFormatting` event.
Try something like this :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value as string))
    {
        e.Value = "NULL";
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

If necessary, you can also add a column condition with the `e.ColumnIndex` property.

Comment: i tried this and it is not working. can you please check my updated code

Comment: You must be new developper ? CellFormatting is called for every datagridview cell. So you just have to replace `string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value as string)` in my answer by `e.Value == DbNull.Value` or whatever makes sense in your case.

Comment: yes i am new developer and am happy to meet people like you with skills and willing to share their knowledge. i did that and it shows as not formatted. invalid arguments

Comment: if(e.Value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                e.Value = "NULL";
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }

Comment: Did you try with the exact code I posted, without any modification ?

Comment: it loaded the whole grid cells with null. i want to make it null if someone didn't fill the cell or ommited it

Comment: i did without modifications and all the cells became null

Comment: You have to change the condition with the one that fitted your case. Add a breakpoint in the CellFormatting function to help you identify the condition to set.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how i can get a go ahead like when adding in coding please

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (!dr.IsNewRow)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= dr.Cells.Count - 1; c++)
                {
                    if (dr.Cells[c].Value == null)
                    {
                        dr.Cells[c].Value = "NULL TEXT";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it doesnt get to this line dr.Cells[c].Value = "NULL TEXT";
                            i have three columns and i want it to loop through all these index.
                            string _Car = dr[1].ToString();
                            string _Dealer = dr[2].ToString();
                            string _Model = dr[4].ToString();